# I am trying to get a list of all classes in a package, but searchResult.getClasses(); requires an argument

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am trying to get a list/reference to all the classes in a particular package using the Burningwave Maven package. Here's my code:

```
public Collection<Class<?>> listCommands() {
    ComponentSupplier componentSupplier = ComponentContainer.getInstance();
    PathHelper pathHelper = componentSupplier.getPathHelper();
    ClassHunter classHunter = componentSupplier.getClassHunter();

    CacheableSearchConfig searchConfig = SearchConfig.forPaths(
        pathHelper.getAllMainClassPaths(),
        pathHelper.getPaths(PathHelper.Configuration.Key.MAIN_CLASS_REPOSITORIES)
    ).by(
        ClassCriteria.create().allThoseThatMatch((cls) -> {
            return cls.getPackage().getName().matches(".*springframework.*");
        }));
    try (SearchResult searchResult = classHunter.loadInCache(searchConfig).find()) {
        return searchResult.getClasses();
    }
}
```

[IntelliJ IDEA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA) says that I need another argument in the getClasses() method.

When I try to run it, I get the following error.

> Error:(105, 32) java: method getClasses in class org.burningwave.core.classes.SearchResult cannot be applied to given types; 
> required: org.burningwave.core.classes.CriteriaWithClassElementsSupplyingSupport 
> found: no arguments 
> reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Answer (score 1):

Replace the `SearchResult` type in your try/catch block with `org.burningwave.core.classes.ClassHunter.SearchResult`, e.g:

```
    try (org.burningwave.core.classes.ClassHunter.SearchResult searchResult = classHunter.loadInCache(searchConfig).find()) {
        return searchResult.getClasses();
    }}
```